# SSRS Date Range Filter

Tags: date, datetime, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I want to apply a Date Range filter on a report just like in SCSM Default report. In my report I used this query:

```
IncidentDimvw.CreatedDate BETWEEN (@StartDate) AND (@ENDDATE)
```

In the parameter properties I selected datatype as Date/Time which gives me a datepicker like calendar but I want some interactive view here just like the [SCSM Default reports has](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9Ja4.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't get that out of the box, you just get the calendar. You have to develop your own user interface for running reports if you want something like that.

Comment: Thanks Chris, Kindly tell more how I can prepare that interface, in order to be able to develop that. Or you can give me any reference link.